# Can I get British citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, uk-citizenship

I was born in 1982 in Libya. At the time, my father, a Libyan, was living in the UK on a normal visa. He eventually acquired British citizenship in 1986. I am Libyan.

Can I get British citizenship as well?

Comment: Where were you born and what is your citizenship? Is it the same as your father's before he became a British citizen? I think it's unlikely because he was not a British citizen when you were born.

Comment: Hello Dorothy i was born in Libya and my citizenship is Libyan .. yes it's same

Comment: You were born before 1983, so the citizenship checker might not be too useful: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen but you are most likely not a British citizen, and the only way you can get it is through living legally in the UK and then getting ILR and naturalise afterwards

Answer (score 1):

As you were born prior to your father obtaining British citizenship, you are probably not a British citizen. You would have to emigrate to the UK and [qualify for naturalisation](https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen/check-if-you-can-apply), It takes time and you should [review the immigration options](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration) in advance of applying for a visa.

Comment: Is there no path to citizenship for the minor child of someone who naturalizes in the UK?